# $E$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Let $f(x)=x^2-2 \in \mathbb{Z}_5[x]$.

$f(x)$ is irreducible.

Let $\xi$ be a solution of $f(x)$ in an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

How can I show that $E=\mathbb{Z}_5(\xi)$ is a splitting field of $f(x)$ ??

Comment: Can you tell what's the general form of an element in $\;\Bbb Z_5(\xi)\;$ i?

Comment: $$\mathbb{Z}_5(\xi)=\{f(\xi)g^{-1}(\xi), f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_5[x], g(\xi) \neq 0\}$$

Comment: Well, yes...but there's a much simpler way to that: $\;\Bbb Z_5(\xi)\;$ is a two-dimensional vector space over $\;\Bbb Z_5\;$ , and any element in it is of the form $\;a+b\xi\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb Z_5$ . Anyway, as you choose to represent the elements of that field, it is clear both $\;\xi\,,\,\,-\xi\;$ are in it.

Comment: I see... Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: @Timbuc Could you also explain me how we show that the splitting field $E$ has $25$ elements??

Comment: in fact we have $\;\Bbb Z_5(\xi)\cong\Bbb Z_5[x]/\langle x^2-5\rangle\;$ , and it's fairly easy to get convinced that every element in this last quotient ring (a field, in fact) is represented by a polynomial in $\;\xi\;$ of degree at most one, and there are precisely $\;25\;$  such elements in our case...

Comment: @Timbuc I got stuck right now... Could you explain it further to me??

Comment: this is a rather messy subject to be explained by this means, though it is one of the most beautiful there are in basic mathematics. Try to read a little about this in your book/notes, and if you have some specific question write down a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the two roots are $\xi$ and $-\xi$, you have that the splitting field is $\mathbb{Z}_5(\xi, -\xi) = \mathbb{Z}_5(\xi)$.

Comment: How do we know that the roots are $\xi$ and $-\xi$ ?? Since the polynomial is second degree, we know that it has at most $2$ solutions. We know that $\xi$ is one solution. How do we know that $-\xi$ is the other solution??

Comment: Since $\xi^2 = 2$, you have $(-\xi)^2 = \xi^2 = 2$ as well.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: Could you also explain me how we show that the splitting field $E$ has $25$ elements??

Comment: @MaryStar: hint: $\deg(x^{2}-2) = 2$, and $|\mathbb{Z}_{5}| = 5$. In general, what do you know about the cardinality of $F(\xi) \cong F[x]/m_{\xi}(x)$, if $F$ is a finite field of cardinality $p$ and $m_{\xi}(x)$ is the minimal polynomial for $\xi$ over $F[x]$?

Comment: @AWertheim I got stuck right now... Could you give me some hints??

Comment: @MaryStar: think of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}(\xi)$ as Timbuc suggested: it is a two dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}(\xi)$ whose elements are of the form $a + b\xi, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}$. Now count. How many elements are there in $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$? Hence, how many choices are there for the coefficients $a, b$? Now it remains to show that all elements of this form are distinct, if this is not already obvious to you. I leave this to you, with the hint that $x^{2}-2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$, and hence must be* the minimal polynomial for $\xi$.

Comment: There are 5 choices for a and 5 for b. Does this mean that there are 25 elements in $\mathbb{Z}_5$?? I haven`t understood how to show that all elements are distinct...